# Is there an add on or a tool to edit rig/bone motion path, instead of using the graph editor?

Tags: add-on

I've been making human animation lately by using the graph editor and the motion path tool to fix the way my rig moves. But I find fixing the motion from the graph editor is time consuming. It would be faster if could juest edit the motion path, and the graph editor adjust accordingly.

I wonder is there an add on for that?

I use Blender 2.79

Comment: You can try Motion Trail Addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__pXnegxkcM  included in Blender or buy https://www.blendermarket.com/products/motiontrail3d

Comment: Motion Trail Addon is unusable for rig.

Comment: MotionTrail3D from blender market seems to be working with some limitations, did you check that one too?

Comment: MotionTrail3D is for version 2.8 above. I'm using 2.79 and have to use that version or slightly below.